# How can I fetch the access code from final window?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-oauth

I'm trying to do a simple OAUTH application with the Google api.

In the middle of the procedure I'm trying to fetch the access code from an opened window after the authorization since the opened window passes through multiple redirects. I was wondering how can I get the code from the final page before closing so I can continue with using it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>quick demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

<img src="folder/mGHPI.png" ng-click="login()">
</body>
<script>
    var app= angular.module("app",[]);
    var url;
    var openedwindow;
    var code;
    app.controller("ctrl",function($scope,$http,$window){
        $http.get("url").then(function(response){
            url=response.data
        });
        $scope.login=function(){
            openedwindow=$window.open(url,"sign in with google","width=500px,height:700px")
            code =openedwindow.document.URL;

            console.log(code)
        };
        //window.opener.postMessage("my  url is :"+location.href,"*");

        window.onmessage = function(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    })
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I need more information about that las t page in order to help you. What does it contain? Is the information you in the HTML or in the URL?

Comment: sebastion that one  information i'm looking to get is everywhere in the title ,in the url , in the html yet i don't how to get it !
the opened window passes through choosing the account then authorizing then i get the page which full with my needed code everywhere so it passes through multiple pages and i need the last one 
in the past after authorizing the account the destination was a page in my server and the code was sent to it but now i guess they have updated it so it takes you to a page in the google servers sebastion lplease let me know if you need anything else